# how do to height set with pixel then auto after

Tags: css, height

I currently have a box set to `width: 153px;` and `height: auto;` however when the page loads because there is nothing within it the box it has no body.

**How do i make it load with height: 51px and then change to auto once images are added?**

**what have i tried?**

I tried using `height: 53px auto;`
setting a height on the div in the html.

I'm sure its something simple but I can't seem to work it out. Any help given is appreciated and I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is invalid!

```
height: 53px auto;
```

Use it this way:

```
height: 53px;
height: auto;
```

Instead you can have a `min-height` and set it to `53px`.

```
min-height: 53px;
height: auto;
```

Comment: I tried that as well it just uses the auto height and the 53 doesn't work.

 `div#pricebox5{
             
             
             border:1px solid #E1E1E1; 
             background: white;
             width: 153px;
             height: 53px;
             height: auto;
             
                
}`

Comment: @KennenLasuni Check my updated answer now... :) Use the second form.

Comment: I had to wait 15 mins it just let me about 1 min ago.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
min-height: 53px;
height: auto
```